# Menu como do facebook

Tags: android, facebook, menu

Estou querendo criar um menu como o da imagem (parecido com o do facebook) a baixo alguém saberia como desenvolver? como devo procurar, tutoriais exemplo. Obrigado!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É melhor usar o Navigation Drawer da Própria biblioteca do android

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nesse projeto, disponível no GitHub e também na PlayStore:

GitHub: https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ActionBarCompat

PlayStore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.liveo.navigationliveo

Creio que está dentro da sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta da uma olhada na biblioteca abaixo:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

E tem o tutorial abaixo também:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/